# pandas dataframe format from elements with multiple identifiers

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV file with the following format.  Imagine the white spaces are comma seperated.

```
                                    slot0                          slot1  
Serial     Timestamp     Height     Width     Score     Height     Width     Score    ....
FA125       2015_05      215.00     125.01    156.02    235.23     862.23    135.52   ....
```

This goes on for thousands of rows and repeats for many slot#'s with this pattern.  The slot# is associated with a "Height, Width, and Score" who it is centered on.  That is, slot0 corresponds to the first Height, Width and Score and slot1 corresponds to the second Height, Width and Score.  Each slot has three measurements.

I'm having trouble finding the best way to stick this data into a pandas.DataFrame where I associate the slot number to particular heights, widths and scores, but especially the Serial or Timestamps.

One thing I have thought of was something like this, but it's not as clear if I can do better.

```
Serial     Timestamp  s0_Height  s0_Width  s0_Score  s1_Height  s1_Width  s1_score  ....
FA125       2015_05    215.00     125.01    156.02     235.23     862.23   135.52   ....
```

It seems a little awkard in this form, but if it's the only way I guess I can manage.

```
# Maybe something like this?
pd.DataFrame({'FSJ1503007N-ct0': ['20150311_021738', 140, 123, 213]}, ['timestamp', 's0_height', 's0_score', 's0_width'])
```

Keep in mind I can adapt the CSV in any way to instantiate the DataFrame, but the problem its that I'm not sure the best way to create the DataFrame with this data.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# just to create a string buffer, you don't need this if you have csv file
from io import StringIO  

# replicate your csv file structure
line1 = ','.join(['slot' + str(x) for x in range(3)]) + '\n'
line2 = 'Serial,Timestamp,' + ','.join(['Height', 'Width', 'Score']*3) + '\n'
np.random.seed(0)
data = np.random.randint(100, 1000, size=9)
line3 =  'FA125,2015_5,'+','.join([str(x) for x in data]) + '\n'
csv_buffer = line1+line2+line3

Out[40]: 'slot0,slot1,slot2\nSerial,Timestamp,Height,Width,Score,Height,Width,Score,Height,Width,Score\nFA125,2015_5,784,659,729,292,935,863,807,459,109\n'


# read your file, set the first 2 columns as index, the rest using multi-level column index
level1 = ['slot'+str(x) for x in range(3)]
level2 = ['Height', 'Width', 'Score']
multi_level_columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([level1, level2])

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv_buffer), index_col=[0,1], skiprows=[0], header=0)
df.columns = multi_level_columns

Out[62]: 
                  slot0              slot1              slot2            
                 Height Width Score Height Width Score Height Width Score
Serial Timestamp                                                         
FA125  2015_5       784   659   729    292   935   863    807   459   109

# you can reshape the original df 
df.stack(level=0)

Out[63]: 
                        Height  Score  Width
Serial Timestamp                            
FA125  2015_5    slot0     784    729    659
                 slot1     292    863    935
                 slot2     807    109    459
```

Answer (score 1):

It really depends what kind of calculations you want to do on your data.

If you simply skip the first row, your csv will be read in as:

```
  Serial Timestamp  Height   Width   Score  Height.1  Width.1  Score.1  ....
0  FA125   2015_05     215  125.01  156.02    235.23   862.23   135.52  ....
```

which may be sufficient for your needs.